# Wpf MVVM stringformat for -999 999 999 999 $

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, string-formatting

I would like to know if there is a way to use `StringFormat` in the `XAML` to format a textBlock this way : -999 999 999 999 $.

The "-" sign must be displayed only when the amount is negative.

I am new to WPF and I didn't find any answer for this exact format.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at custom numeric formats? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx WPF examples should be enough to describe how to make a converter, then all you need to do is create the format string

Comment: Can down voting users please explain to down voted users why they have down voted? Otherwise, how can they ever learn from their mistakes? I can only assume it is because this user does not appear to have made any attempts to solve their problem.

Comment: @Sheridan I'm pretty sure that I did explain it

Comment: My team and I tried a lot of things, did a lot of research but I guess that we didn't use the best keywords. However, thanks for the links! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following format:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat={}### ### ### ### $}" />
```

You can find out more from the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) page on MSDN.